# A stronger version of the Rosen’s subsequence theorem.

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

The following question was asked in my combinatorics exam -

“Let $n$ be a positive integer. Exhibit an arrangement of integers between $1$ to $n^2$ which has no increasing or decreasing subsequence of length $n + 1$.”

This question has a very similar structure to the [Rosen’s subsequence theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2149576/1277478), and I am aware of its proof using the pigeonhole principle, as given in the link above by @Rajdeep.

But i am not really sure on how to provide the requisite construction for my question above — the pigeonhole principle fails here as we have $n^2$ numbers and $n^2$ pairs, if we proceed in a similar fashion as done in the proof linked above.

So could somebody provide me with some hints or solutions ? I may be completely wrong as well in the using pigeonhole principle for this problem, so different solutions are also welcomed.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1040400/a-sequence-of-n2-real-numbers-which-contains-no-monotonic-subsequence-of-more also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1144232/proving-erd%c5%91s-szekeres-bound-with-counterexample and several other questions linked there.

Comment: It's weird to call it "Rosen's subsequence theorem", when the result is not due to Rosen but to [Erdős and Szekeres](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erd%C5%91s%E2%80%93Szekeres_theorem). This is even mentoned in the comments of the question linked to here.

Comment: @MishaLavrov, i was not aware of this fact, our professor taught it as Rosen’s subsequence theorem.I thank you for informing me .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Split all the numbers in groups of $n$ numbers and then make the following sequence (each string is one group):

$$n^2-n+1, n^2-n+2,…,n^2,$$
$$…,$$
$$2n+1,2n+2,…,3n,$$
$$n+1,n+2,…,2n,$$
$$1,2,…,n.$$

Every strictly increasing subsequence is of maximal length $n$, since for every number in the sequence all the numbers that are greater than it are in the same group. If you want to make a strictly decreasing subsequence, you have to take at most one number from each group, so again the length is at most $n$.